# Javascript MVC - observer location

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Where should I place the observers when from the View I call a function from the Controller that changes the Model and I should notify the observers.

The observer should be placed in the Controller or in the Model?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement observers in view or controller.But i would implement the observers in controller then the view is decoupled from the controller and the controller takes care of all the "control" stuff.